# React how to disable submit button until form values are input

Tags: reactjs, forms, disabled-input, submit-button

I'd like to keep the submit button in my form disabled until the values of the each input are at least one character, not including white space. I tried using trim() and it seems to work until I click submit.

Here is my Form component:

```
export function Form(props) {
  const { form, inputChange, postQuiz } = props;

  const onChange = () => {

    inputChange()
  }

  const onSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault()
    const question_text_input = document.getElementById("newQuestion");
    const question_text = question_text_input.value
    const true_answer_text_input = document.getElementById("newTrueAnswer");
    const true_answer_text = true_answer_text_input.value
    const false_answer_text_input = document.getElementById("newFalseAnswer");
    const false_answer_text = false_answer_text_input.value
    postQuiz({ question_text, true_answer_text, false_answer_text })
  }

  return (
    <form id="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <h2>Create New Quiz</h2>
      <input onChange={onChange} placeholder="Enter question" />
      <input onChange={onChange} placeholder="Enter true answer" />
      <input onChange={onChange} placeholder="Enter false answer" />
      <button 
      id="submitNewQuizBtn"
      disabled={
        form.newFalseAnswer.trim().length >= 1
        && form.newTrueAnswer.trim().length >= 1
        && form.newQuestion.trim().length >= 1
        ? ""
        : "disabled"
      }
      >
        Submit new quiz
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default connect(st => st, actionCreators)(Form)
```

With the code above, the submit button stays disabled until I type at least one character in each input (doesn't count whitespace, like I wanted), but as soon as I click submit I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim').

I don't understand why that happens. Is using trim() on the form Object incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `two states` in your `component`. One for `input` and another for the `button`.

```
const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('') // For input
  const [isdisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false) // For button

  // when input is changing this function will get called
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setInput((prevState) => (e.target.value))
    if(e.target.value.trim().length < 1) {   // Checking the length of the input
      setIsDisabled(true)  // Disabling the button if length is < 1
    } else {
      setIsDisabled(false)
    }
  }

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Code...
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input type='text' placeholder='email' value={input} onChange={onChange} />
      <button id='button' type='submit' disabled={isdisabled}>Submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you have multiple `inputs` change the `onChange` function and `input state` accordingly.